# workspace: Not the correct type

Tags: asana

I'm trying to create a new task via the api.

The call is:

**curl -u my_token: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks -d "name=demo_task" -d "workspace=875236917006"**

and this is the response:

**{"errors":[{"message":"workspace: Not the correct type"}]}**

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

The ID you've provided for a `workspace` does not refer to a workspace, it refers to something else. Perhaps you're passing it a project ID instead?

Try running `curl -u my_token: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces` which will give you a list of all the workspaces you are in. The ID you pass in must be one of those.